# Is flock & exec safe in bash?

Tags: bash, lock

The "standard" locking snippet I've seen goes something like...

```
(
    flock -n 200 || exit 1;
    # do stuff
) 200>program.lock
```

Is it safe (testing seems to say so) to use `exec` at that point? Will the subprocess retain the lock?

```
(
    flock -n 200 || exit 1;
    exec /usr/bin/python vendors-notcoolstuff.py
) 200>program.lock
```

I vaguely remember exec'd processes retain open file descriptors and since flock uses file descriptors it should work. But I cannot find any documentation that makes that definitive and clear.

For the record, this is specific to Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, locks are preserved across `exec`. Locks are preserved across the underlying system call [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), as long as the file descriptor remains open. File descriptors remain open across `execve` unless they have been configured to be closed on exec, and file descriptors created by shell redirection are not marked as close-on-exec.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. Exec just replaces the process image, but it's still the same process so the OS-level locks associated with it remain the same.

It's very easy to verify that it works:

**lock**

```
(
    flock -n 200 || exit 1;
    echo "locked"
    exec ./script
) 200>program.lock
```

**script**

```
sleep 100
```

Try running `./lock` twice within then next 100 seconds. You'll only get the lock once, ergo `exec` does not release the lock.